# Ubuntu 18.04 dock icons don't drag and drop.

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock

On Ubuntu 18.04 when rearranging dock by drag and drop, icon drags but does not drop-- flies back to former place.

Comment: Dropping in an empty space won't work, but dropping between two icons should work fine (and that's enough to rearrange the icons).

Comment: @pomsky-- Dropping between icons works exactly how I wanted. Thank you.  -- frank